# Android Room strange behavior with ids in relationship

Tags: android, relationship, android-room

Im noticing something weird with Room.
I have two entity: Wine and Bottles
A bottle belongs to only one wine, but a wine can have multiple bottles (one to many)

So, i've got the folowing model:

```
@Entity(tableName = "wine")
data class Wine(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id_wine")
    val idWine: Long = 0,
    val name: String
)

@Entity(tableName = "bottle")
data class Bottle(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id_bottle")
    val idBottle: Long = 0,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id_wine") val idWine: Long,
    val comment: String
)
```

The relation:

```
data class WineWithBottles (
    @Embedded val wine: Wine,
    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "id_wine",
        entityColumn = "id_bottle"
    )
    val bottles: List<Bottle>
)
```

And finally there is the database room prepopulate callback:

```
private val roomCallback: Callback = object : RoomDatabase.Callback() {
            override fun onCreate(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
                super.onCreate(db)
                thread {
                    val bottleDao = instance?.bottleDao()
                    val wineDao = instance?.wineDao()

                    wineDao?.insertWine(Wine(1, "a"))
                    wineDao?.insertWine(Wine(2, "a"))
                    wineDao?.insertWine(Wine(3, "a"))

                    bottleDao?.insertBottle(Bottle(0, 1, a))
                    bottleDao?.insertBottle(Bottle(0, 1, b))
                    bottleDao?.insertBottle(Bottle(0, 1, c))

                }
            }
        }
```

I mention that i provide Wine and Bottles Entities to the Room @Database annotation

So the problem is, when i'am observing a `getAllBottles() : LiveData<List<Bottle>>`, i get every bottles, everything is fine

But when i'm observing `getWineWithBottles(): LiveData<List<WineWithBottles>>` i've got one bottle per wine, even though i've set the id_wine of all bottles at 1

Each WineWithBottles object has a wine, and a SINGLE bottle in the list:
[WineWithBottles(wine=Wine(idWine=1, name=a), bottles=[Bottle(idBottle=1, idWine=1, comment=a)]), WineWithBottles(wine=Wine(idWine=2, name=a), bottles=[Bottle(idBottle=2, idWine=1, comment=b)]), WineWithBottles(wine=Wine(idWine=3, name=a), bottles=[Bottle(idBottle=3, idWine=1, comment=c)])]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change relation's condition to `wine.id_wine=bottle.id_wine`:

```
data class WineWithBottles (
    @Embedded val wine: Wine,
    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "id_wine",
        entityColumn = "id_wine"
    )
    val bottles: List<Bottle>
)
```

Comment: Such a dumb mistake, i'v confused myself with the attributes
Thanks for pointing it out :)